# Apply Geometry on face selection

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying do apply different modifiers to only certain parts of my mesh. I want to use this selection to play with dual mesh or to apply a pattern to only these faces but I am struggeling to process my selection further.
At the moment I am only able to select those faces seperate from the rest of the mesh and I dont know how to merge them back together.
Is there a way to achieve this without seperating the meshes?

Thank you for the help.

[image: My attempt] [image: The Geonodesetup so far]

Comment: I don't think so; if that was available, it would be in the form of a Selection socket on the Subd and Dual Mesh nodes. They could, theoretically, be added later, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: Thats sad, thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to create a pattern like a spiral pattern or smth like that to follow those selected faces? I dont nessesary need dual mesh, but a way to let a pattern follow my surfaces and only be applyed to such selected surfaces.

Comment: Not so easily that I could just tell you in a comment. Would depend on what kind of setup, exactly? Maybe post a question with good detail. Share your model you wanna alter on blend-exchange.com etc.

Comment: Thanks @Kuboå I am preparing a question like that right now.